# wordpress jquery not working even in no-conflict mode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i want to show an alert box when a div is clicked in wordpress 
in functions.php i wrote the code

```
function load_script_files(){
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs',get_stylesheet_uri().'/js/scripts.js',array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script_files')
```

;

In scripts.js i wrote the following js code

```
jQuery(".click-div").click(function(){
    alert("The div was clicked.");
})
```

But it is not showing any alert boxes. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Are both scripts actually loaded? does the .click-div exists? Do you execute your script after the DOM finished loading?

Comment: I couldn't see any errors in console. script files are linked in header and .clicl-div exists. How to know whether dom finished loading?

Comment: View source and check if your file is included or not? and open it and check your file can be open. Also check `.click-div` is exist in html or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` not `get_stylesheet_uri()`

`get_stylesheet_uri()` it return stylesheet url.

```
function load_script_files(){
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js',array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script_files');
```

Comment: are you using child theme or only parent theme?

Comment: parent theme, custom made

Comment: go to the page source. you can see the scripts.js? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZXdQ.png

Comment: No. I cant see . It is not loading it seems.

Comment: do you have this function `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in footer.php?

Comment: Yes  wp_footer () is called.

Comment: <?php
            function load_script_files(){
  wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js',array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script_files');

register_nav_menus(array(
  'primary' => __('Header Menu'),
  'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
  'social'=>__('Social Menu')
));

Comment: Showing an error :Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://wiki.local/wp-content/themes/orcid/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0”.

Answer (score 0):

If both files are really loaded (check network tab in your browser console) I suspect the problem is that you try to attach the event listener to an object that does not yet exists.

Simple solution to that is to execute your code when DOM is loaded completely:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".click-div").click(function(){
       alert("The div was clicked.");
    })
});
```